# Can't get stock number on Category

Tags: twig, opencart-3

### EDIT: I'm on OpenCart 3.0.3.2

I want to get the product's stock number on my Category page, so i added this to catalog/controller/product/category.php

```
$data['products'][] = array(
                    ...,
        'stock'       => $result['quantity'],
);
```

and when i add this to [mytheme]/template/product/category.twig:

```
<p>TEST {{ product.stock }}</p>
```

it only shows the 'TEST' string without the variable, i just can't pass the .stock variable's value to my .twig file, any suggestions?

Comment: It should work. Just maybe you forget refresh modifications and clear cache. And maybe `<p>TEST {{ product.stock }}</p>` placed on twig file not in products loop. Try to place it below this string... `<h4><a href="{{ product.href }}">{{ product.name }}</a></h4>`

Comment: Did you verify `$result['quantity']` to start with?

Comment: thank you, it was really only the cache.. i cleared it out and it worked instantly, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the cache and refresh the modifications did it